# Basic Rigid-Body Setup: Displays perfect in Render preview but is completely broken in the actual render

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

This is my second consecutive project where I follow a tutorial to The Letter and it does not work. This time, it's this basic [Object Breaking Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xdrz7icUvC4) by *Blender Made Easy*.

While I have spruced up my scene a little bit (versus the tut), the essence is exactly the same. I have two rigid body animation systems set up with a simple keyframe to hide the 'whole' sphere right before impact, revealing the 'shards' sphere instead.

[Here is the link to the blend file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ajGNMi0R1ko0vnSt4ZIDZ9uH_Uv28fN8/view?usp=sharing)

As with my previous project, I have confirmed that this looks 100% correct in my 3D viewport in render view. But when I actually Render the Animation, the results are a spectacular failure. Which is to say that nothing actually falls or appears in frame on top of my surface. There simply is no physics scene.

Is it a requirement that all physics be baked? Because if so, I will need to manually bake the physics of like 200 shards. And that feels wrong considering that i have rendered out rigid body scenes a while back without any baking.

I really hope I am missing something obvious because I'm about at my wits end with literally anything interactive with Blender.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The only surefire solution I have found is to select all my Rigid Body actors and then select: **Object** - **Rigid Body** - **Bake to Keyframes**. This ends my sim but turns everything into proper manually-moving objects that renders with no problem.